# What was Rangui's plan at the Military Gala?

Tags: otome-yokai-zakuro

In Episode 5 - *Sticky Trap*, Rangui, the Black Widow, lures Lieutenant Hanadate to a room (presumably hers considering the number of bodies already there) and stings him up.

Near to the end of the series, we learn that Lieutenant Hanadate is Lord Omodaka, current chief of the Village of Oracles. Near the end of Episode 9 - *Joy of Love*, Omodaka says he is attracted to Zakuro as a part of the plan to defeat the kokkuri spirit. When everything is over, Zakuro thanks him for the ruse, but he insists that he's a poor lair. At the end of the episode, we see Rangui in bed with him commenting on that. When Omodaka gets up, he puts his mask back on, so we do know that Rangui knows how Omodaka looks like behind his mask.

So then what was her plan at the Military Gala in Episode 5? Her jealousy for Zakuro didn't start until Omodaka called her a filthy demon, which was much later.

Comment: @nhahtdh any better?